# How to extract otf - font information

Tags: php, fonts, opentype

I am trying to extract all font information from an otf-file. I want to generate a small image for each glyph and each extended otf-feature.
Currently I am using the PHP class "OTTTFont" to fetch all available UTF-8 characters, which seems to work quite good. But I have no clue, how to fetch the feature information, so that I can render them.

So do you know a way to get easy access to the otf-features? (PHP is not necessarily required. I would love a way with imagemagick only or maybe a Perl-script).

Thank you in advance

Comment: when you say OTTTFont, are you referring to my OTTTFont class from https://github.com/Pomax/PHP-Font-Parser?

Comment: Yes, I do. A nice and handy class by the way.

Comment: which features do you refer to, though? the opentype "feature" is a structure used in GPOS/GSUB tables, and is not currently supported by the php font parser. If you mean metrics, those are already extracted per glyph (see fonttest.php)

Comment: My goal is to find all special symbols (as I understand, those are stored in the otf features section) and print them out. I already found the GPOS/GSUB tables but I have no idea, how to print those special icons on an image. I am currently using imagemagick to draw out all symbols on an image, but am unable to put those special icons, which seem to be located in the features section, on an image.

Comment: if you want all the characters encoded in the font (including normally inaccessible ones due to use in ligatures, etc), then you don't need GSUB/GPOS at all, you just need the cmap, which will specific all the characters that the font encodes.